# Changing a web page using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect, confirmation

I'm a college business student trying to build a website with a business model.

I'm building a website where I want to allow users to signup. Right now I'm using action: signup.php to store the user into the database.  After the user is successfully inserted, I redirect the page back to the index.html where the form was submitted.

My question is, how can I reference JavaScript to change the login from display:block to display:none and sign up confirmation from display:none to display:block through my PHP tag?

I'm currently using `$_GET` to grab the success/fail status from signup.php and I want to use an IF statement to execute the correct JavaScript code.

**UPDATE**

I was advised to instead set all div's to block and use a PHP IF statement to display the login or signedup divs. However, after implementing the changes, the index.html still cannot distinguish the success/fail status. Here is my code below:

signup.php:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) 
{           
$qry = "INSERT INTO logins (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', SHA('$password1'), '$email')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $qry);
    if($result)
    { 
    header('Location: index.html?signup=success'); 
    }
}
else
    {
    header('Location: index.html?signup=fail');
    }
```

index.html: Head

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>

    <?php
    if(!empty($_GET['signup'])) 
    {
    $signup = $_GET['signup'];  
    }
    ?>

  </head>
```

index.html: Body

```
  <body>
    <div id="container">

      <?php
      if(!$signup)
      { 
      ?>
      <div id="login">...</div>          
      <?php
      }
      ?>

      <?PHP
      if($signup) 
      {  
      ?>
      <div id="signedup">...</div>

        <?PHP
        if($signup == 'success')
        {
        ?>
        <div id="confirmation">...</div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>       

        <?PHP
        if($signup == 'fail')
        {
        ?>
        <div id="failure">...</div>
        <?php
        }
        ?> 

      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </body>
```

As of now, after the user submits the form they are inserted into the database.  The problem is that once they are redirected to the index.html, the php does not recognize the success/fail status and consequently only displays the login form.

Answer (score 0):

That PHP code needs to go in your `<head>` or `<body>` section.  You have it before `<html>` right now.

And yeah, `onload = function();` should probably be `window.onload = function;`

Comment: You don't want to execute the function, just assign the function itself to onload (remove ())

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
onload=signedup();
```

You need to attach to the onload handler correctly:

```
window.onload = signedup;
```

Now, this isn't the best way to do things (it waits for EVERYTHING to be loaded), so if you happen to have jQuery included in your page, it'll be more efficient:

```
$(function(){ signedup(); });
```

Also, move the PHP to inside the HEAD tag since it prints out a script - and scripts should generally be in the HEAD tag.

---

Now, to take a different direction - why don't you just do it with PHP by printing out the HTML only if it's needed:

```
<?php if(!$signedup) { ?>

    <div id="login"> ... </div>

<?php } ?>
```

This is probably the way to go in this case!

Comment: so I just adjusted the code to include 'window' and I removed the () but when I refresh the page it's still displaying: " window.onload=signedup;";}}?> " at the top. 

Can you specify where I need to put my code? Is the PHP before HTML okay? Also am I using 'echo' correctly to reference the javascript?

Comment: Yeah, the PHP is in the wrong place...let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the improved method. I tried it out to the best of my abilities but i'm falling short of my desired result. Can you check out my edited question?

Comment: You really need to raise a new question as it'll get fresh attention. Your new code has a whole separate issue which other people will be able to help with.